# Location of SQLite database in eclipse for android using phonegap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap and developing html pages for android but I dont know how to view the tables and its corresponding database in I am using Eclipse Juno. I Know it is somewhere in DDMS can anyone tell me the path where my tables and database is located in SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow this path

`DDMS`->`data`-> again click `data`-> `your package name`(com.example.app)->`databases`->there you have your database

After finding your db file [click this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data)

Comment: thanks saw the database but I cant view my tables how to view it in eclipse itself

Comment: @Ramkiran can you please tell me what is exact db location? because sometimes i found in `database` or `app_database` or sometime `local_storage` also. i am totally confused. please guide in right way