# Saving/retrieving Sqlite database on Computer hard disk Phonegap using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, cordova

similar question already asked, but I am unable to find database on disk

```
DDMS->data-> again click data-> your package name->databases->db
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708705/location-of-sqlite-database-in-eclipse-for-android-using-phonegap)

I am building a simple Android mobile application using **phoneGap V 2.7.0**.In application I want to implement the database feature.

I used Sqlite database for storing data. It is working fine. It stores the data, inserts the data, and gets the data. But when I need to push the database on my hard disk I am not able to see the database on **app_databse** folder.

For Retrieving database from eclipse to computer hard disk I used **SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1**.

Below steps I used to see the database from the eclipse.

> DDMS=>File Explorer=>data=>data=>=>app_database
>   folder.
>
> Minimum Required SDK: API 8: Android 2.2(Froyo) Target SDK: API 16:
>   Android 4.1(Jelly Bean) Compile with: API 17 Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean)
>   PhongGap V: 2.7.0; Android V: 4.2 Eclipse Version: 4.3

I used Below code for setting data,getting data from sqlite database.

Creating Database and table

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", OnDeviceReady, false)

function OnDeviceReady() {
    alert("PhoneGap is ready");
}

function onCreate() {
    try {
        var mytx = window.openDatabase("Contact", "1.0", "Contact", 1000000);
        mytx.transaction(funCreateData, funsuccess, funerror)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
    }
}

function funCreateData(tx) {
    try {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ContactList (id unique, name varchar)');
        alert("created");
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.message);
    }
}

function funsuccess() {
    alert("Debug on Success");
}
```

Inserting Data into Sqlite Database

```
function onInsert() {
    var mytx = window.openDatabase("Contact", "1.0", "Contact", 1000000);
    mytx.transaction(funSetData, funSetsuccess, funerror)
}

function funSetData(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ContactList (id, name) VALUES (1, "XYZ")');
}

function funSetsuccess() {
    alert("Success");
}
```

Getting the Data from Sqlite Database.

```
function onSelect() {
    var mytx = window.openDatabase("Contact", "1.0", "Contact", 1000000);
    mytx.transaction(funGetData, funGetsuccess, funerror)
}

function funGetsuccess() {
    alert("Success Select");
}

function funGetData(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select * from ContactList", [], successQ, funerror);
}

function successQ(tx, result) {
    var len = result.rows.length;
    alert(len);
    var fname = result.rows.item(1).name;
    alert(fname);
}

function funerror(err) {
    alert("Error" + err.message);
}
```

PS : should I ask my question with other similar one ?